# Is there a functionality that is available only with Internet Explorer 9 and not supported in Modern Browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I come up to ask this question because our client sometimes reports browser issues. Such as layout issues using CSS or functionality issues using JavaScript.

They are still using old Internet Explorer version. My question in my mind is why aren't they moving to other top modern browsers, such as Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox or Opera or any listed from [here](https://techviral.net/best-web-browsers-2019/). Since IE support with older version ended 1/12/16, [see reference here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support). And also, using up-to-date software is the best way to avoid the attackers [Here](https://securingtomorrow.mcafee.com/consumer/consumer-threat-notices/software-updates-important/) is the link why up-to-date software is important even though it talks about in general.

Btw, I can't ask the client why because they don't have technical knowledge. I also don't know how to open it up with our senior.

Maybe the answer is that they are used to with IE9. Programmatically, is there anything I've been missing? Like functionalities that are only available with that version and not available in the latest version of top browsers?

Please don't answer functions that are marked deprecated and now removed. Those are maybe upgraded unto something. Also, please provide a citation if available.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18687/why-dont-people-upgrade-their-browsers

Comment: You can search for some of your CSS in https://caniuse.com/ and see if some code is not compatible for all browsers and which ones.

Comment: Sort of the opposite [there is a lot that IE9 doesn't support but other browsers do](https://caniuse.com/#compare=ie+9,edge+76,firefox+71,chrome+80). Although, there *are* specific IE things that may work on IE9 but won't (or not the same) on other browsers. It's hard to give an exact list, but IE has historically had a lot of non-standard features. Some were later standardised and went into other browsers but others not. Supporting IE has been a major hindrance for *all of web development* since there has been IE and standards it could break.

Comment: [Microsoft security chief: IE is not a browser, so stop using it as your default](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-security-chief-ie-is-not-a-browser-so-stop-using-it-as-your-default/)

Comment: there's https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537512(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN , you should be able to serve an alternative style sheet

Comment: Its about time for them to renew the hardware *(software upgrades will follow)* even if it fully fill their needs at the moment. hardrives do not last for ever to start with, for a compagny, it would be wised.

Comment: The only thing I remember from IE9 is conditional comments. `<!--[if IE]> Visible in IE <![endif]-->`, but I'm sure there must be more.

Comment: You could use [F12 developer Emulation tools to simulate IE 9 Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyliv.png), then check whether there has some error, then, based on the error to [check whether the function is supported IE 9 browser](https://caniuse.com/#compare=ie+9,edge+76,firefox+71,chrome+80).